# How to install jQuery qTip2 using Bower in Visual Studio?

Tags: jquery, visual-studio, gruntjs, bower

I just recently started using Bower/Grunt to manage my client-side dependencies for my ASP.net MVC application. Every package I've ever used contains a JavaScript source file, until I tried to use the jQuery qTip2 package.

I thought maybe since it included a gruntfile I could build it using the Task Runner in Visual Studio 2015 but the Task Runner doesn't seem to know the file is there, even if I include it in the project.

Does anyone have experience using Bower/Grunt with qTip2 in Visual Studio? How do you typically use a bower component if it is missing the final script and css files?

Comment: Hi Sam. Did the below answer help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you checked [qTip2 repository on github](https://github.com/qTip2/qTip2) you will find that it doesn't have a `bower.json` file. This files contain the necessary information for `grunt-wiredep` to work with.

You can install it from its git url using

```
bower install --save https://github.com/qTip2/qTip2.git
```

This will install qTip2 and add it to your `bower.json` file. Now you need to define which files you need to include by providing an override in your bower.json like this:

```
"overrides":{
    "package-name": {
      "main": [
        "path-to-js-file",
        "path-to-css-file"
      ]
    }
  }
```

You can optain the "pachage-name" from your `bower.json` after the installation is finished.